# Syntax highlighting suggestion

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

I was editing a lot of questions lately without proper syntax highlighting. These occurs mostly on questions with Facebook tag. So it would be great to get highlighting just with these tags without any edit or adding language hint

**TAG**-------------------------------------------**LANGUAGE TO USE**

1. `facebook-javascript-sdk` ------------------------------------> Javascript
2. `facebook-php-sdk`------------------------------------------------> PHP
3. `facebook-ios-sdk`, `facebook-iphone-sdk`----------------> C
4. `facebook-c#-sdk`--------------------------------------------------> C#
5. `facebook-java-sdk`, `facebook-java-api`------------------> Java
6. `facebook-android-sdk`, `android-facebook`---------------> Android
7. `facebook-actionscript-api` ---------------------------------> Javascript
8. `facebook-fql`-------------------------------------------------------> SQL( Not so sure about this one)

Other tags not related to Facebook that should also have default highlighting are

`laravel`, `laravel-3`, `laravel-4`, `codeigniter-2`, `codeigniter-3`, all version of `cakephp-x.x` etc.

All of these should have PHP as their default highlighting.

There must be a lot of tags like these, but I have encountered these a lot and I believe these should be implemented for better viewing of these questions and answers.

Comment: P.S. There is no ActionScript highlighting language. But out of curiosity, I looked - [tag:actionscript] uses `lang-js`, [tag:action-script-2] uses `<none>`, and [tag:actionscript-3] uses `default`. Hm.

Comment: Shouldn't we tag such questions with relevant tag? E.g. Question tagged with `facebook-javascript-sdk` should also be tagged with `javascript`. If this is okay then it will highlight syntax with relevant language. [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18015016/1369235)

Comment: @hims056 Firs of all, Not everyone will do that e.g. new users who doesn't have any idea about syntax highlighting. Secondly, I think that kind of tagging doesn't make any sense either. If it has to be tagged with `javascript` too, `facebook-javascript-sdk` should have default highlighting set to `Javascript`. That solves all the problems.

Comment: @animuson I changed it to `Javascript`.

Comment: @animuson Uhh, AS2 and AS3 (along with plain actionscript) should have ActionScript syntax highlighting, right? JS has different keywords and stuff. (and the dashes are inconsistent `:(`)

Comment: @Doorknob: Well, like I said, there is no ActionScript language in the syntax highlighter.